How to fetch a resource from a github release?
I have a public github repo with some climate data at https://github.com/garyo/sea-surface-temp-viz/releases. Each day a github action creates a new release with some assets.
I'd like to create a separate web app that uses those resources (png and json files) to do some further processing/visualization, but I'm getting trapped by CORS issues. I can download the files in the browser, but my web app front end refuses due to missing CORS headers.
I know I could upload the files somewhere else where I'm in control of the outgoing headers (make an S3 account with keys, create a bucket, upload in my action, bla bla bla), but they're already there, with perfectly fine github URLs. Seems like it shouldn't be so painful.
I even tried using the github API to find the release, get the asset's raw URL and fetch that, but it has the same CORS problem even though the doc says it should support CORS. I even tried a free CORS proxy but couldn't get it to work. Why would anyone care about the origin of a github release asset?
Here's some code I tried:
async function getGithubAssets() {
  const latestReleaseUrl = 'https://api.github.com/repos/garyo/sea-surface-temp-viz/releases/latest'
  const result = await fetch(latestReleaseUrl)
  const releaseData = await result.json()
  const assets = releaseData.assets // array of assets
  let sstTextureUrl = assets.find((elt: any) => elt.name == 'sst-temp-equirect.png').url
  let anomTextureUrl = assets.find((elt: any) => elt.name == 'sst-temp-anomaly-equirect.png').url
  let sstCmapUrl = assets.find((elt: any) => elt.name == 'sst-temp-equirect-cmap.json').url
  let anomCmapUrl = assets.find((elt: any) => elt.name == 'sst-temp-anomaly-equirect-cmap.json').url
  const fetch_opts = {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/octet-stream'
    }
  }
  return {
    sstTexture: await (await fetch(sstTextureUrl, fetch_opts)).blob(),
    anomTexture: await (await fetch(anomTextureUrl, fetch_opts)).blob(),
    sstCmap: await (await fetch(sstCmapUrl, fetch_opts)).json(),
    anomCmap: await (await fetch(anomCmapUrl, fetch_opts)).json()
  }
}

Here's a ts playground to test it. Open dev tools, run it, you'll see the fetch errors.

I am running into the exact same need, and explored the exact same path looking for a solution. No success yet. I have some public data hosted on github releases, and I'd like to be able to explore it from the browser on github pages using https://perspective.finos.org/examples/. Any
